# datatables custom sort (only pre activates)

Tags: jquery, sorting, datatable, datatables

I have some custom sort code defined by sType: "my-num-html" on that column.

My column data is like this:

- AB 332
- BC 664
- CD 325
- KF 576

And it orders by default as such:

- CD 325
- AB 332
- KF 576
- BC 664

It completely ignores the letters... I'm trying to make it not ignore the letters.

Then I have extended it in "dataTables.naturalSort.js"

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
        "my-num-html-pre": function (a) {
            console.log("my-num-html pre");
            var x = String(a).replace(/<[\s\S]*?>/g, "");
            console.log("nh: " + x);
            return x;
        },

    "my-num-html-asc": function (a, b) {
        console.log("my-num-html asc");
        return naturalSort(a, b); //((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0));
    },

    "my-num-html-desc": function (a, b) {
        console.log("my-num-html desc");
        return naturalSort(a, b) * -1; //((a < b) ? 1 : ((a > b) ? -1 : 0));
    }
});
```

The problem is that it shouldn't ignore the letters and should print the asc/desc functions... The pre prints my column in the logs (using console.log).

When the page loads, even the "pre" doesn't load.

When you click the column header: the pre loads, but that's it and it's incorrect order.

When you click it again: the pre loads again, but still incorrect order.

The "asc" and "desc" logs NEVER get printed.

**EDIT:: The AJAX "fnserverdata" is being used, and whenever that's called the order gets reset back to the AJAX data.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was sorting through server side and I can't say why it wasn't activating that code. I still haven't figured out why it doesn't sort with a custom sort afterwards.